# 'Expecting a top level declaration' when creating a Kotlin Class

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am getting this error `Expecting a top level declaration` on this very simple class declaration

```
public class NetworkConnectionInterceptor implements Interceptor{

}
```

I have done `invalidate cache` several times but the error still exists, any ideas please?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention to the file type, its `.kt`, meaning its `Kotlin`.

What your'e attempting here is `Java`

```
public class NetworkConnectionInterceptor implements Interceptor{

}
```

So please do it this way if you want a `Kotlin` class,

```
class NetworkConnectionInterceptor : Interceptor {

}
```

But if you really want this as `Java`, you then have to create a new file as `Java`

Comment: Thank you much, I am beginner on mobile aplication